# activate a javascript function when a jQuery accordion is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have an accordion in jQuery.

```
$( "#accordion1" ).accordion();
```

Defined as:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    hello,
  </div>

  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    World
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to activate a javascript function when the user clicks on the H3 responsible for section 2? As its not a link or a button I'm a bit stumped as to how to do this. The problem is that the user is working in one window and will go to the other window to see updates so I need to update that section by calling a js function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the eq() function as Selector:

```
$("#accordion h3:eq(1)").on("click", function() {
     // Something here
});
```

You can find useful info about the eq() function [here](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
$("#accordion h3:eq(1)")
```

Or you could just add an ID to the relevant heading and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#accordion h3:eq(1)').click(function() {
    // Your function here
});
```